# Cмысл использования метода TypedArray.recycle()

Tags: android

В чём смысле использования метода `TypedArray.recycle()`? В документации написано, что этот метод

> Recycles the TypedArray, to be re-used by a later caller. After
>   calling this function you must not ever touch the typed array again.

что означает, насколько я понимаю, что этот метод перерабатывает TypedArray, чтобы повторно использовать его позже, и после вызова этой функции никогда не следует использовать TypedArray. Возможно, я неправильно перевела, но смысл этого метода с таким описанием мне не очень понятен... Т.е., значит ли это, что метод  `TypedArray.recycle()` выступает в роли деструктора объекта TypedArray, который говорит сборщику мусора, что этот объект TypedArray можно убрать?

Answer (score 1):

По моему так

Если внутри произвольного метода набрать в TypedArray свойства/аттрибуты из файла стилей, то в конце метода сборщик мусора не оставит от TypedArray ничего. `.recycle()` позволяет уберечь TypedArray от сборщика мусора. Извлеченные атрибуты стилей останутся действительны. Соответственно повторно создавать TypedArray для извлечение тех же аттрибутов не нужно.